# Data Analysis Question from a Stats Novice (Hierarchical Multiple Regression and sample size assumptions)

Tags: regression, anova, multilevel-analysis, interaction

I'm working on my dissertation and have only a very basic knowledge of stats. I am assuming all of you have a much better understanding and I need some clarification:

I am comparing two groups (minorities and Caucasians) using 1) ANOVA and 2) moderated hierarchical regression. My sample is very skewed (119 minorities and 850 Caucasians). I am working with someone who has a better understanding of stats than I do and she said I need a subsample was of equal size to the minority sample in order to avoid skewing the results at the recommended minimum of 15% in each categorical variable (i.e. non-minority participants and minority participants) according to Pedhazur (1997). However, speaking with my advisor and another professor they question the creation/necessity of a subsample.

Do I need to create a subsample of Caucasians equal to the sample of minorities to run ANOVA and Moderated Hierarchical Regression or do I compare the two using the original sample of 969? I have already written and run the syntax and written the results section for the subsample and am trying to determine if I need to put in another 10 hours of work running and writing up the stats from the larger sample.